# What is encodeURIComponent() in momentjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

So this is my code:

```
var input = '2015-07-13T22:00:00Z';
var output = encodeURIComponent(input);

console.log(output);
```

How can i use `encodeURIComponent` in momentjs?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a Javascript method : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: Why would you do that? Do you understand what they do?

Comment: This function is used to encode characters to UTF-8 format, why would you want to use it with moment? Maybe use moment('2015-07-13T22:00:00Z').format('format-needed');

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could make some sense using JS encodeURIComponent() function on an *ISO 8601* date only if you need to use that value as an URL parameter, passing it 'as-is' for example to a *REST* endpoint...

**UPDATE 1:**

You could use it, for example, this way:

```
var input = '2015-07-13T22:00:00Z';
var output = encodeURIComponent(input);
var endpoint = 'https://example.com/endpoint/date=' + output;
```

**UPDATE 2:***

Or, this way:

```
var input = moment().toISOString();
var output = encodeURIComponent(input);
var endpoint = 'https://example.com/endpoint/date=' + output;
...
```

Comment: I need to get this format first: `2015-07-13T22:00:00Z`. How?

Comment: ??? That is the format of your input... You HAVE that format already...

Comment: I need to get it dynamically with `new Date()` for example... and then encode it like you did

Answer (score 0):

It encodes the URI of the component so that it can be accessed easily.

For example -

> https://www.google.com?myquery=my query

becomes

> https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%3Fmyquery%3Dmy%20query

after using encodeURIComponent()

But if you need to change the format of your date, you should use .format() method.